# ObjectAnimator generate NotFoundException

Tags: android, objectanimator

I'm writing an app that animates various ImageViews by setting an array of Drawable resource IDs to it via an ObjectAnimator.

Here's the sample code I've extracted to highlight the issue:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     private final int[] drawableIDs = new int[] 
        {R.drawable.ic_launcher_background};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void startNow(View view) {
        ImageView iView = findViewById(R.id.image);
        Animator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(iView, "imageResource", drawableIDs);
        animator.start();
    }
```

And the layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_radio"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go!"
        android:id="@+id/btn_go"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="startNow"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And I'm getting the following exception.

```
    W/PropertyValuesHolder: Method getImageResource() with type null not found on target class class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
I/Choreographer: Skipped 1207 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01d5540e (t=212 e=21518) (error -2147483647)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.spoofer.animatortest, PID: 25686
    **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1d5540e**
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:204)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1315)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.createDrawableIfNeeded(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:235)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:86)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
        at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallIntMethod(Native Method)
        at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.-wrap7(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$IntPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1240)
        at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)
        at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateBasedOnTime(ValueAnimator.java:1316)
        at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1446)
        at android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(AnimationHandler.java:146)
        at android.animation.AnimationHandler.-wrap2(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame(AnimationHandler.java:54)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:964)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:778)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:710)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6798)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
D/OSTracker: OS Event: crash
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'
```

The Resource "#0x1d5540e" it cannot find is NOT the resource ID of the drawable set on the ObjectAnimator.  I have no idea where this ID is coming from.

Strangely, if I make the resource IDs array larger than one, it doesn't throw the exception:

```
 private final int[] drawableIDs = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground};
```

**Update:** It's thrown only when the given int array has a single element. Reading ObjectAnimator/ValueAnimator docs, I'd expect it to work with one value but maybe I'm wrong.

Any idea's what would cause this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Strangely, if I make the resource IDs array larger than one, it doesn't throw the exception:
private final int[] drawableIDs = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground};

Comment: Update:
It's thrown only when the given int array has a single element.

Reading ObjectAnimator/ValueAnimator docs, I'd expect it to work with one value but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `imageView` has no public getter for imageResource. You can try it with an array of `drawable` instead and use `drawable` as animated property.